# Flex / Flash - How do I open the .swf in a browser window that doesn't have the browser control bar or menu?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4

The title essentially is the question, how do I open the .swf without the browser's control bar junk? and maximize the window?

Comment: Do you want to know how to have a swf displaying in full screen mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the javascript **open** function.

See here : http://www.javascripter.net/faq/openinga.htm

It will be something like

```
window.open('yourswf','window name','width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,resizable=0,location=0...');
```

Hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When the browser has focus, press the `alt` key. This should bring up the file menu. Or you can drag and drop the swf onto the browser.

On windows, you can right click the SWF file and click "open with" from the menu. You can then select your browser. If your browser does not show up in the menu click "choose program.." and selected it from there.

Not sure if this is what you wanted from your question.